# How to create a file with a set size in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

The file format I'm handling has a header of 8192 bytes at the front of the file. In order to create an empty file, I need a zeroed out header (*file format spec is out of my control*).  My current solution is this :

```
with open(fileName, mode='w+b') as f:
    for i in range(8192):
        f.write(b'\x00')
```

Is there a better (**more efficient**) way to do this ?

Comment: I guess you could do `f.truncate(8192)` after opening it to create a sparse file containing zeros.

Comment: @alani Does that work when the file didn't exist before I opened it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Truncate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) is much more efficient than writing out null bytes:

```
with open(fileName, mode='wb') as f:
    f.truncate(8192)
```

Comment: And it works when the file does not exist in the first place ?

Comment: @AmyLucyRose Yes, this works when the file was not existing beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) builtin:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(8192))
```

From the docs:

> The optional *source* parameter can be used to initialize the array in a
> few different ways:
>
> - If it is an *integer*, the array will have that size
>   and will be initialized with null bytes.

Comment: This was the first solution I was going to include in the post, the reason I changed it is because it instanciates 8 KiB of zeros in memory.

Comment: @AmyLucyRose 8KiB isn't much, and doing so is likely better than doing 8k single-byte writes. If you're dealing with the filesystem then creating a tiny buffer in memory is never going to be your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You might multiply python `bytes` by integers similarly to `str`s, so for example `x = b'\x00' * 3` is equivalent to `x = b'\x00\x00\x00'` therfore instead of:

```
with open(fileName, mode='w+b') as f:
    for i in range(8192):
        f.write(b'\x00')
```

you might do:

```
with open(fileName, mode='w+b') as f:
    f.write(b'\x00' * 8192)
```

which `write` once.

Comment: This is the best answer so far ! I'm not going to mark the thread as resolved just yet, but if nothing better comes this is the solution.

Are you sure it doesn't instantiate the whole bytes object though ? I don't want to take up 8 KiB of memory during the write process

Comment: It will instantiate all the bytes. The argument has to be evaluated into a temporary object before the call.

Comment: But I doubt you need to worry about that. The only way to reduce this is to reduce the 8192 to a small number.